# How to recover Eclipse deleted java files from Mac?

Tags: java, eclipse, data-recovery, file-recovery

I straight up deleted my java files after moving them to a different java project thinking I had a second copy of them in my old java project folder. Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: No need to panic. I found my solution. Right click and "restore from local history". Phew, that was a close call.

Comment: If you haven't already done so set up 'Time Machine' backups now.

Answer (score 4):

Don't panic.

Right click upper level package(folder). Select "Restore from Local History.." from the popup menu.

If you are lucky, you'll find your files there.

Comment: I thought the deleted files would be in trash can, but it wasn't so I panicked a little haha

Answer (score 2):

Project --> 
Right Click --> Restore From Local History --> Select files --> Restore

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it was that simple.

Comment: This only works if you didn't check the "delete from disk" checkbox.  Next thing you need to do is to set up backups and/or check your code into an off-machine source code repository!!

Comment: Yeah right, but "delete from disk" option only comes when you delete a project.